# Probability theory on the transfinite

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, set-theory, foundations, nonstandard-analysis

The usual fomalization of probability through $\sigma$-algebras and $\sigma$-additive measures can effectively model (countable) infinite chains of trials. This is usually done by defining a countable sequence of measurable spaces $(E_n, \mathcal{F}_n)$ (that represent the $n$-th trial), a starting probability measure on $(E_0, \mathcal{F}_0)$ and a sequence of transition probability kernels $K_n$ from $(E_0 \times\dots\times E_{n-1}, \mathcal{F}_0\otimes\dots\otimes\mathcal{F}_{n-1})$ into $(E_n, \mathcal{F}_n)$ that formalize the conditional interactions between the subsequent trials.
Then the probability measure over $\bigotimes_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E_n$ that represents the overall experiment (i.e. such that its finite-dimension restrictions are coherent with the known kernels and the known starting probability measure ) exists and is unique by Ionescu-Tulcea's theorem.

Now my question is:

- Can we extend this formalization process (and Ionescu-Tulcea's theorem) to effectively model transfinite chains of trials?

That is, given a transfinite sequence of "measurable" spaces $(E_\alpha, \mathcal{F}_\alpha)_{\alpha \in \kappa}$, a starting "probability measure" on $E_0$, and a transfinite sequence of transition "probability" kernels (in the limit trials maybe we could work with direct limits of kernels...) can we find a space that represents the overall sequence of trials?

I used the quotes before as I don't think this can be done within the boundaries of standard probability theory. In fact we'd need to go beyond $\sigma$-algebras in order to be able to work with events of uncountable dimensions , i.e. that are assessable only after uncountably many trials (e.g. given an uncountable sequence of tosses of a *highly* unfair coin,  we'd like to work with the events regarding the cofinality of heads or tails ).
Moreover we'd need *perhaps* to work with measures taking values in a field extension of the reals as we'd deal with events of infinitesimal probability, hence leaving the usual interpretation of probability off the table.

Has this been done in some way?

I ask this question because recently I have been thinking of how to model extremely rare random "events" that manisfest themselves consistently only in a (uncountable) transfinite sequence of trials.

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you're looking for exaclty, but the Kolmogorv's extension theorem is probably relevant

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I am aware that this is a vague question, but the intuition behind it is solid: what I'm looking for is a way to generalize Ionescu-Tulcea's theorem for transfinite chains of trials. Kolmogorov's extension theorem is not useful here, since the ($\sigma$-)algebra it gives us is too poor to account for events that are assessable only in the (uncountable) transfinite.

Comment: Have you studied stochastic integration? Stochastic processes can't be defined in general for the reasons you laid out, but if we assume a process is continuous (or right-continuous), then it is characterized by its value at a countable dense set of times (the finite-dimensional distributions of the process). There are other tricks too, for example, to define white noise directly we would need an uncountable set of i.i.d. Gaussians, so we show that Brownian motion acts as we would expect integrals of white noise to and work with that instead. Can you use similar tricks for your problem?

Comment: @forgottenarrow I'm studying it, but the process I want to model is intrinsically discrete and has nothing to do with standard stochastic processes (uncountably indexed) that are usually studied, also because the space in which this process takes values is not homogeneous at all (there are uncountably many different measurable spaces). The latter consideration is another reason why Kolmogorov's extension theorem is not useful here.

Comment: @Lorenzo I understand that. My point is that standard probability theory is not well-equipped to handle uncountable collections of random variables in general, so I don't think you'll get an answer without providing more details. Even so, it may be possible to do what you're trying to do using the structure implicit to your specific problem.